# How to find correct field name that is used for advanced searching

Tags: jira

When doing advanced search in JIRA, how can know what is the backend field name for the highlighted label?

[image]

I'm trying to filter only "Type = Epic" but when I try typing "Type" in advanced search, I'm not finding the appropriate auto suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Type should work. issuetype works as well

Jira Data Center at least allows aliases for some fields in JQL.
These are the fields and their aliases:

issuetype, type
remainingEstimate, timeestimate
updated, updatedDate
originalEstimate, timeoriginalestimate
id, issue, issuekey, key
created, createdDate
due, duedate
resolutiondate, resolved

This is not documented anywhere I could find

Comment: That sucks. `issuetype` is working. But I'm surprised as to why they aren't documented. What if I wanted to filter on another field (maybe custom even) and I can't find it in the autosuggests?